# SOAP result null?

Tags: java, soap, service

I have problem with my soap client. I have generate client part from wsdl using apache cxf.
I'm using Netbeans IDE and Maven. I also created HeaderHandler where I print soap response and it seems to be valid. But when I call web service method from my client a always get null value without any exception.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Update:

link to wsdl http://carecoprod.blueway.fr:8180/engine53/52/WSDL?name=AAA00_WsB2B&version=1&type=EAII

Client code:

```
{
    AAA00WsB2B ss = new AAA00WsB2B(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    HeaderHandlerResolver h = new HeaderHandlerResolver();
    ss.setHandlerResolver(h);
    AAA00WsB2BPortType port = ss.getAAA00WsB2BPort();
    System.out.println("Invoking aaa00WsB2B...");
    AAA00WsB2BIN input = new AAA00WsB2BIN();
    VarAAA v = new VarAAA();
    v.setLogin("*******");
    v.setImmat("*******");
    v.setTypeReq("******");
    v.setMdp("*******");
    input.setVarAAA(v);
    AAA00WsB2BOUT _aaa00WsB2B__return = new ObjectFactory().createAAA00WsB2BOUT();
    _aaa00WsB2B__return = port.aaa00WsB2B(input);
    System.out.println("aaa00WsB2B.result="+_aaa00WsB2B__return.getVarAAARetourWs().getCO2());


}
```

Comment: are you sure your webservice is running?

Comment: Yes i'm sure. In my HeaderHandler i get response which i expect.

Comment: Can you post some code and a link to the WSDL?